# How to get multiple active ranges from getActiveRangeList() trigger function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

When the code below is called in a trigger function onEdit or onChange it doesn't work properly:

```
var selection = sheet.getSelection();
var ranges = selection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
```

[image]

When selecting multiple ranges (see the screenshot) the variable

```
var ranges
```

contains only the range H1:H15. The range J1:J15 is simply not in the array.

**An interesting fact is, when the code snippets above are called outside of the trigger functions – they work as expected, i.e., they detect multiple selected ranges.**

The full code of a trigger function:

```
function onEdit (e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var selection = sheet.getSelection();
  var ranges = selection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();

  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
      Logger.log('Active Ranges: ' + ranges[i].getA1Notation());
  }
}
// Active Ranges: H1:H15
```

**Edit**: There is a bug reported to Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115931946 Please vote to increase its priority if you're not lazy ;-)

Comment: Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50769121/how-are-non-adjacent-ranges-handled-by-the-onedit-simple-trigger-in-google-scr). I think it addresses your issue.

Comment: Have you tried going from `SpreadsheetApp` instead of from `e`

Comment: @I'-'I I've tried var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getSelection(); var ranges = selection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges(); And it doesn't work as well.

Comment: If you've confirmed the issue, post it to issuetracker.google.com

Comment: I've voted for it on [issuetracker.google.com](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115931946). Please, vote it too ;-)